# Kubernetes Ingress: How can I expose two ports on one path?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, websocket

I have a GCE Ingress configured and working with SSL on port 443. I'm trying to get port 28080 pointing to my [standalone actionable server](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#standalone).

I currently have this for my Ingress yaml:

```
# web-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gke-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /ws
        backend:
          serviceName: websocket
          servicePort: 28080
  tls:
  - secretName: gkecert
    hosts:
    - example.com
  backend:
    serviceName: web
    servicePort: 443
```

If I set the path to / for the websocket service, it screws up the root path (error 503). [From what I've read](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1655), an ingress cannot handle 2 ports on one path. How then are people connecting their front-ends to websocket servers without separating by path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your second Backend service is missing the path, if you want to use  ingress with one host and two services you should add the path. 
See [ingress fanout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#types-of-ingress) then your ingress should be like:

```
# web-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gke-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: gkecert
    hosts:
    - example.com
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /ws
        backend:
          serviceName: websocket
          servicePort: 28080
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web
          servicePort: 443
```

> You must specify the path if you want to use the same host.
>   You can connect the front-ends to websocket servers without separating by path using different host.
>   See the documentation on how we do it [Link](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/c4fa60f66f7430389c47c47675e2ce3d9ff9668a/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/multi-tls/multi-tls.yaml#L66)

Comment: "You can connect the front-ends to websocket servers without separating by path using different host" - That seems to confirm that it's not possible to have two ports go to 2 services on the same path for the same host. The example I gave works, but I was hoping to get the `/ws` path to `/`. Your example 404s at `/` for the web, not sure why.

Comment: My mistake, your example seems to be equivalent to mine, and cleaner. Thought it was 404'ing because it doesn't redirect http to https.

Comment: when it's 404 dafault backend, that mean the rules doesn't apply or there is no rules. ingress only expose the port 80 and 443 to expose other port you need to setup a load balancer like below.

Comment: apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: websocket
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 28080
      targetPort: 80080
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: standalone

Comment: Port 28080 is exposed in the example in the question, it's just the path that bothers me.

Comment: you need to specify the path for each service listening. Did you try to curl inside the node  the endpoint using the path and port? check if you get a response then move to the ingress.

Comment: Port 28080 is connecting and responding to the websocket service just fine. Everything is working. I was wondering how I could have the `/ws` path be `/`. It's just a vanity thing.

Comment: because you can't have two services is the same path these are different app each service is listening on his app for example you have two app running the one running on "28080" and the other in "443" try first to deploy one service "websocket" on the path "/" and check the connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

> Kubernetes Ingress: How can I expose two ports on one path?

As already stated in comments by [Alioua](https://serverfault.com/users/473887/alioua), it's not possible. I would also say that mapping a single path to two different port numbers doesn't make much sense from the perspective of the `ingress` logic.

What you expose externally is some specific path of the `http/https` URL, so the only ports exposed externally are `80` and `443`.

An ingress `path` refers to exactly one backend `Service`, that exposes (internally from the cluster perspective) your app (or rather a single microservice that your complex app consists of) on a single `port`.